# Set ApplicationId on Win7 for SWT/RCP application

Tags: java, windows-7, swt, rcp

Win7 uses applicationId for the grouping and according to this

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294827
(comment #4 and comment #8)

Display.setAppName() should have set the application id in the first time.

With Eclipse 3.7, I try to call Display.setAppName() before PlatformUI.createDisplay() like the below.  Still, all shells dumped to one taskbar icon:

```
Display.setAppName(id); // id is ready from a file and different for every session
Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
```

**Use case**

The same binary is used for various purpose (e.g. UAT vs PROD) and run on the same PC.  It is much easier to manage if properly grouped in the taskbar.  This is especially useful as we tweak all detached views to have its top-level shell, i.e. separate item on the taskbar.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use Display.setAppName() to control the grouping BEFORE calling PlatformUI.createDisplay().

```
Display.setAppName("MyApp");
Display display = Display.getDefault();
PlatformUI.createDisplay();
```

Pre-create display so that display is created customized app name, which controls task-bar grouping under Win7. PlatformUI.createDisplay() will grap the same display for internal image initialization as long as they are called with the same thread. Calling PlatformUI.createDisplay() directly uses app name and version from product info with no customization available.

Display with the same app name will be grouped under the same icon in Win7 taskbar.
Display.setAppVersion() is simply ignored.

Comment: Works for other platforms too